# How to implement single thread scheduler in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thread-safety, scheduler

I want to execute the processes every 00sec.(Server time)
But, these processes may take a minute or more.

When process is still running,
is there elegant way to block same process(method) from running? (I don't want to run the process)

(If process#2 is over,
process#2 must run independently even if process#1 is running.)

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
    public void process1() {
        //doing something during 
        //It may take a minute or more
    }
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
    public void process2() {
        //doing something during 
        //It may take a minute or more
    }
```

Comment: what you want not able to understand, like you want to say process2 run independently without impact of process1(process1 either complete or running ) or something else ?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: so what is the problem in above code

Comment: But I don't want that two or more same processes(method) run concurrently.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself: *"If process#1 is over ... even if process#1 is running"* --- How can it be *over* and still *running* at the same time?

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistype...
If process#2 is over,  
process#2 must run independently even if process#1 is running.

Comment: @ilsulee firstly you need to clarify what you want to do, then ask question properly as mentioned by Andreas

Comment: I edited the comment
If process#2 is over,  
process#2 must run independently even if process#1 is running.

Comment: Can we relax prepositions to start time at 00? For example is it okay to run job every minute (without specification of exact time)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself with the source code below.

```
@Service
public class Scheduler {
    @Autowired
    private Job1Service job1;   
    @Autowired
    private Job2Service job2;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
    private void job1() {
        new Thread(job1).start();
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
    private void job2() {
        new Thread(job2).start();
    }}
}
```

```
public class Job1ServiceImpl implements Job1Service, Runnable{
    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

    public void run() {
        try {
            if(lock.tryLock(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                try {
                    logger.info("job1 start");

                    /* do heavy job
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
                        logger.info("test#1 : " + i);
                        for(int j = 0 ; j < 999999999 ; j++) {
                            int k = 1;
                            k++;
                            k++;
                        }
                    }
                    */
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    logger.error("job#1 error", e);
                }finally {
                    logger.info("job #1 end");
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }else {
                logger.info("skip job#1. job #1 is running still");
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e) {
            logger.info("Job #1 Aborted", e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Job2ServiceImpl implements Job2Service, Runnable{
    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

    public void run() {
        try {
            if(lock.tryLock(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                try {
                    logger.info("job2 start");

                    /* do heavy job
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
                        logger.info("test#2 : " + i);
                        for(int j = 0 ; j < 999999999 ; j++) {
                            int k = 1;
                            k++;
                            k++;
                        }
                    }
                    */
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    logger.error("job#2 error", e);
                }finally {
                    logger.info("job #2 end");
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }else {
                logger.info("skip job#2. job #2 is running still");
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e) {
            logger.info("Job #2 Aborted", e);
        }
    }
}
```